# Xcode 5 shrinks every object on Storyboard by 20px

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

Recently i've opened my old (`XCode 4.6`) project in `XCode 5` and it has automatically converted my `UIStoryboard` to a new format (SDK 7).
When i run it on `iOS 7 simulator`, everything is OK, but when i'm trying to run it on `iOS 6`, my layout is pretty much broken. Height of every object in Storyboard is shrinken by `20px`.
Same thing happens when i set View as-`iOS 6` and earlier. And when I'm trying to open it in Xcode 4.6, it shows the same picture (shrinken objects).
I expect that this is something NavBar-related.
I don't use `Autolayout`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a topic currently under NDA.

Comment: Please move the question to the Apple dev forum.